# Remove duplications and sort array by most frequent tags

Tags: javascript, function, sorting, mapping, filtering

I have array of objects. That objects has array of tags.

For example:

```
const tags =
[{
      id:"1,
      Category: "Food"
      tags: ["One", "Two", "Three"],
},
{
      id:"2,
      Category: "Drinks"
      tags: ["Four", "Five", "Six"],
},
{
      id:"3,
      Category: "Herbs"
      tags: ["One", "Two", "Three"], // These tags are duplication of the first object and should not be in final list of tags (output).
}];
```

Example of my JSX code:

```
tags.map(tags =>
        [...new Set(tags.tags)] // ?? I was playing with set, because I need delete duplications and also sort the final output by most frequent used tags
          .map(tag => (
            <Link to={"/" + tags.category + "/" + tag}>
              {tag}
            </Tag>
          ))
      )
```

I am trying to delete duplicated tags in final output list of tags. One of solution I've tried, as you can see in my code is [...new Set(tags.tags)] - because I need two things = 1) Sort most frequent used tags and also delete duplications. This solution works well for the sorting (with simple array works for both), but because of the array of objects, there are still duplications. I've tried some magic with the SET in codepen, but with no success. Do you have please any idea how to solve it? I know there is lodash, but I would prefer to use rather own solution without lib. Thank you!

Comment: Which category should be used for e.g. `One` - `Food` or `Herbs`?

Comment: It doesn't matter: Because I need just output just simple list of (filtered, sorted..) tags. :)

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the array to a Map, and use `Array.forEach()` to add tags with their categories if the tag is in the Map, and count the occurrences of the tag (`freq`). Convert to an array of `[tag, { freq, category }]` pairs, sort by `freq`, and map to JSX:

```js
const { useMemo } = React;

const getTagsWithCategories = tags => Array.from(
  tags.reduce((r, o) => {
    o.tags.forEach(tag => {
      if(!r.has(tag)) r.set(tag, { category: o.Category, freq: 0 }); // init      
      r.get(tag).freq++; // increase freq
    });
  
    return r;
  }, new Map()))
  .sort(([, a], [, b]) => b.freq - a.freq) // sort by freq

const Tags = ({ tags }) => {
  const pairs = useMemo(() => getTagsWithCategories(tags), [tags]);

  return pairs.map(([tag, { category }]) => (
    <a href={`/${category}/${tag}`} key={tag}>
    {tag}
    </a>
  ))
};

const tags = [{"id":1,"Category":"Food","tags":["One","Two","Three"]},{"id":2,"Category":"Drinks","tags":["Four","Five","Six"]},{"id":3,"Category":"Herbs","tags":["One","Two","Three"]}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Tags tags={tags} />,
  root
);
```

```css
a:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```